# Upload Default HTML Report of UFT to ALM

Tags: hp-uft

Is there any way we can automatically export the default **HTML Report** to ALM at the end of each run?

In **tools > General > Run Sessions > Report Format**, if we check HTML Report then **UFT** generates a **HTML Report** for local runs, but if any test is run from ALM or if we specify the Run Results Folder in ALM while running the script from UFT directly instead of "temp folder" then it doesn't generate the **HTML Report** but instead generates the **Run Result Viewer Report**.

The new HTML Report that UFT generates after the 12.50 version is really detailed and good. I wish to use that report and upload it to ALM instead of the Run Result Viewer Report.

I am using UFT 12.54.

Please help me out with this if this can be done.

Comment: I understand you want to add the result to ALM - you can do so by:

     `Set oNewAttachment = 
      QCUtil.CurrentRun.Attachments.AddItem(Null)
       
       oNewAttachment.FileName = FileName` 'Replace with filepath'
       
       `oNewAttachment.Type = 1 'TDATT_FILE
       
       oNewAttachment.Post`

Comment: Yes, I want to add the result to ALM. But the Result should be the default HTML Report not the Run Results viewer report. And I want the result to be uploaded automatically at the end of the run. But the problem is the HTML report is generated after the run ends and even if I'm specifying the result to be generate as HTML Report in "Tools" still I'm getting the Run Results Viewer Report in the ALM.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by the other report than the Run Result Report. However, if the the report that you desire has a path then replace it as indicated in the code and it should work for you. basically it will upload this file (report that you want) and add it in ALM.